Flashy TabBarItem redirect to another page
I added to my code the FlashyBar flutter package but I don't know how to connect to another page when you press any icon from the bar. I tried to add onPressed or onTap but gives error. I see in the beginning some tabItems , should I change something there?
Here is the code
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'post_detail.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flashy_tab_bar2/flashy_tab_bar2.dart';
import 'Influencerprofile.dart';
import 'package:liquid_pull_to_refresh/liquid_pull_to_refresh.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> tabItems = [
    Center(child: Text("0")),
    Center(child: Text("1")),
    Center(child: Text("2")),
    Center(child: Text("3")),
    Center(child: Text("4"))
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          'INFLUFIT.CLUB',
          style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, children: [
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search influencer",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                    )))
          ])),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Location',
                style: TextStyle(),
              )),
          Expanded(
            child: LiquidPullToRefresh(
              //  key: _refreshIndicatorKey, // key if you want to add
              onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tabItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostDetail(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FlashyTabBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showElevation: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: [
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Feed'),
            
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text('Favourites'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('Add'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
            ),
            title: Text('News'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('My profile'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

What I should do? It has to do something with the Index?

All you have to do is provide tabItems.elements
body: Center(
        child: tabItems.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),



I want when I tap one of the icons to send me to a new page

So you want to navigate to new page?
